# Get an image from service

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, service, asp.net-mvc-4

I use MVC4, Razor and C#. I would like to have Service, for example:

```
[WebGet]
[OperationContract]
public string Get(int id)
{
  PictureManager m = new PictureManager();
  Picture p = m.Load(id);
  return Convert.ToBase64String(p.Trunk);
}
```

where:

```
public byte[] Trunk { get { return _trunk; } }
```

And on the client side I would like use it in the same way:

```
<img src="http://MyService/MyPictures/Get?id=21">
```

Is there the same ability? Or maybe I need to use some JavaScript to show a picture on client side? Could you please show me direction?

Comment: Try returning a FileStreamResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return this from your code if your image is a jpeg.

```
return "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(p.Trunk);
```

[Read here for the Data URI scheme.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: Most of of time, this is a very bad design. This will produce the base64 version of the image, each time the html is rendered. If you use twice the image for example, the image will be rendered twice. This will add a huge network overload for html pages. If you create a dedicated image servicing endpoint, you will be able to add cache, control html headers, etc.

Comment: You may read [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/working-with-images-in-Asp-Net-mvc-framework/) to get a descent sample.